# Does hiding DOM elements improve performance?

Tags: performance, angularjs

Lets say I have an HTML div containing numerous form elements that are all watching model values, if I use ng-show, ng-if, or ng-switch on the div to hide it, will this stop angular JS from doing dirty checking on the form elements and thus improve the performance of my app?

I figure that if the bound elements are not visible then there's no need for angular to be checking the values bound to them.

Comment: could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` will only set a CSS `display` style, and will still process the bindings. `ng-switch`, however, will completely comment out the cases that do not apply, which in turn means bindings in those are **not** processed. I agree, however, with Edmondo1984's reply, that I doubt you should base your choices on this. Do not rewrite your `ng-show`s as `ng-switch`es because of this!

You can verify this with the Chrome extension [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk), the performance tab shows which watches are active.