# ngSwitch slows down the APP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a popup directive, and this popups contains different content. Now I use ng-switch for when to show popups content, but this slows down the interface, more time I open the popup, slower it gets.

Now if I use ng-show instead of ng-switch, interface doesn't slow down, but the problem is, that number of watchers doubles.

I am using angularjs 1.4.4, what do you suggest? Almost all my directives have:

```
scope: {
    attrs: '=?'
}
```

and this is a Class with all its data.

Number of watchers:

ngSwitch - 771

ngShow - 1481

Comment: this can be a partial explanation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919083/does-hiding-dom-elements-improve-performance
the ngShow watchers are doubled because elements are also rendered  when condition is false, but the directive only change css display property. Maybe ngSwitch is a bottleneck because dom element insert/delete are more expensive to compute

Comment: didn't help, I know that. Is there a way to fix ng-switch, because I cannot use ngshow, because the amount of watchers is to large.

Comment: without code is difficult to have an idea on how to improve and optimize it. i would try other approach (limiting results or binding once the variable if it's possible). Did u checked why popup are slower everytime you open them? Maybe there are some issue on destroying scope. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Popups are not slower, the problem is that my ng-sortable is slower.

Comment: I found out that ng-transclude in popup slows down the app. Does anyone know why would that be?